# Share CSS between shared components in an Angular component library

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am creating a shared component library for Angular applications. One thing that is not quite efficient is the styling. I would like to be able to share CSS between components and render it on a page only when the component is actually used. Also, styling should not 'leak' in the application.

In CSS you would define classes globally:

```css
.width-1-5 {
  width: 20%;
}
```

And then re-use it:

```html
<header>
  <div class="width-1-5"></div>
</header>
<article class="width-1-5"></article>
```

But with shared components this becomes a bit more complicated. It could be that specific styling defined globally is not used at all in an application who uses the component library.

The solution of [material ui](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) is to create one shared CSS file which you must include together with your shared components:

```scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();
@include mat.all-component-themes(...);
```

But the downside is that it's an extra implementation detail. If you want to use the library you have to know to include this in the application's global stylesheet.

Another downside is that it still contains styling for elements that you might not use.

So what I am currently looking in to is to define modular sass files.

**./shared/styles/width.scss**

```scss
.width-1-5 {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}
```

**./components/header/app-header.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss', '../../shared/width.scss']
}) export class HeaderComponent implements...
```

**./components/article/article.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-article',
  styleUrls: ['./article-component.scss', '../../shared/width.scss']
}) export class ArticleComponent implements...
```

Great! This works, you don't have to include a generic global stylesheet. Also what's really great is that you don't have CSS leaking into your application.

But sadly there is still one gotcha. Angular will create multiple  tags for the same code in the  of the document:

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <!-- ... -->
   <style>.width-1-5[_ngcontent-phg-c16]{flex:0 0 20%}</style>
   <style>.width-1-5[_ngcontent-phg-c15]{flex:0 0 20%}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>
      <app-header _ngcontent-phg-c16 class="width-1-5"></app-header>
      <app-component _ngcontent-phg-c15 class="width-1-5"></app-component>
    </app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

This also does not seem very efficient.

Comment: You may want to look into `:host` selector. Though idk, for me at least, it would be harder to understand that some classes are encapsulated, some shared but named the same. I would go with the global stylesheet way and name them so, that there wouldn't be conflicts.

Comment: How about turning off style encapsulation?

Comment: @Eugene That would leak the styles

Comment: @Remi It all depends on how the code is organized. When you set host class the same as the name of the selector, and use BEM inside, you have no problem. We lived for many years without any encapsulation, it's ok =) But emulated encapsulation is a [problem for performance](https://nolanlawson.com/2022/06/22/style-scoping-versus-shadow-dom-which-is-fastest/).